# Cambio de botones con Ajax o JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo dos botones

```
<input id='pausa' type='submit' name='pausa' class='btn btn-warning' value='Pause'>

<input id='restart' type='submit' name='restart' class='btn btn-info' value='Restart'>
```

He intentado con el siguiente script, pero solo para un mismo botón y que cambie de color, pero mi idea es que cambie de botón:

```
<script>
        $('#pausa').click(function () {           

            var clase = $('#pausa').attr('class');

            if (clase.includes('btn-warning')) {                        
                $('#pausa').removeClass('btn-warning');
                $('#pausa').addClass('btn-info');
            } else {
                $('#pausa').removeClass('btn-info');
                $('#pausa').addClass('btn-warning');
            }           
        });
</script>
```

Mi idea es que con `Ajax` o `JQuery` al pulsar el botón `pausa`, cambie al botón `restart`. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Si subes lo que has probado tendremos un punto de partida desde el que poder ayudarte.

Comment: @phpMyGuel llevas razón, subo lo que he intentado

Comment: @phpMyGuel Ya está editado, pero mi código lo hice para un solo botón cambie de color, pero quiero que cambie de botones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con JQuery basta con usar un display none, por las clases asumo que utilizas bootstrap así que he añadido un `d-none` a tu botón de restart:

```
<input id='pausa' type='submit' name='pausa' class='btn btn-warning' value='Pause'>

<input id='restart' type='submit' name='restart' class='btn btn-info d-none' value='Restart'>
```

y luego en el javascript hacemos el cambio en el evento click del botón pausa:

```
$('#pausa').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('d-none'); //this se refiere al botón pausa
    $('#restart').removeClass('d-none');
}
```

Nota: en caso de que no utilices bootstrap basta con declarar la clase en el fichero de estilos css de la siguiente manera:

```
.d-none{display: none;}
```

Como recarga la página debes añadir una validación al html en php si llega algún dato del submit anterior

```
<?php if(!$_POST['tuvariable']):?> // o $_GET si tu method en el formulario es GET
  <input id='pausa' type='submit' name='pausa' class='btn btn-warning' value='Pause'>
<?php else: ?>
  <input id='restart' type='submit' name='restart' class='btn btn-info' value='Restart'>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`tuvariable` tienes que reemplazarlo por algun valor que se mande en el formulario la primera vez, tiene que ser algun valor obligatorio que siempre se mande, creo que con `$_POST['pausa']` o `$_GET['pausa']` te debería funcionar

Comment: Al tener los botones metidos dentro de un `form`, me actualiza la página y no me hace el cambio del botón

Comment: Y tu quieres que el botón pausa haga submit del formulario? Si ambos botones tienen que hacer submit lo que puedes hacer es que tras la primera llamada compruebes las variables que vienen del get o del post en función de como tengas el formulario y mediante php habilitar uno u otro botón

Comment: Claro, los dos botones los tengo dentro de un `form` y cuando hacemos click en ellos, cada botón hace una función, osea, submit

Comment: puedes añadir el html de tu formulario?

Comment: La verdad es que es un poco complicado ya que yo trabajo en la plataforma `Scriptcase` y las consultas y eso, las hace diferentes y es un código muy largo. ¿Habría otro sitio mejor para que mandarte mi códgio?

Comment: puedes ponerlo por pastebin, de todas formas no es necesario, cuando llames después del primer submit a tu php y se recargue la página tienes que comprobar que tengas alguna petición del submit anterior para mostrar el primer botón, entonces solo te haría falta modificar tu html para ocultar el input que corresponda. Mira la edición de la respuesta

Comment: Vale! Muchas gracias! Así me ha servido!